Tensorflow - Improving accuracy and fixing overfitting
I'm writing a plant classifier program in python using tensorflow. My problem is that the model overfits but also have around 80% acuracy. I want to achive around 90%. As far as I understand to reduce overfitting I have to decrease model complexity, but to improve accuracy I have to increase model complexity.
Here's the code:
training_set = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    'train',
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",
    class_names=None,
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(256, 256),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=None,
    validation_split=None,
    subset=None,
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
    crop_to_aspect_ratio=False
)

#Prepare to use the validation dataset
validation_set = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    'val',
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",
    class_names=None,
    color_mode="rgb",
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(256, 256),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=None,
    validation_split=None,
    subset=None,
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
    crop_to_aspect_ratio=False
)

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten, Dropout, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()

#relu: not linearity function
#padding: relevant at upscaling

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=[256, 256, 3 ]))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(units=512, activation='relu'))

#Output Layer
model.add(Dense(units=1081, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
    learning_rate=0.0001), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

training_history = model.fit(x=training_set, validation_data=validation_set, epochs=10)


And here's the result of the training:
Epoch 1/10
7623/7623 [==============================] - 3816s 498ms/step - loss: 4.1253 - accuracy: 0.2025 - val_loss: 3.5102 - val_accuracy: 0.2980
Epoch 2/10
7623/7623 [==============================] - 3051s 400ms/step - loss: 2.9865 - accuracy: 0.3695 - val_loss: 2.8978 - val_accuracy: 0.4013
Epoch 3/10
7623/7623 [==============================] - 3155s 414ms/step - loss: 2.3822 - accuracy: 0.4674 - val_loss: 2.5107 - val_accuracy: 0.4636
Epoch 4/10
7623/7623 [==============================] - 6592s 864ms/step - loss: 1.9636 - accuracy: 0.5375 - val_loss: 2.3513 - val_accuracy: 0.4911
Epoch 5/10
7623/7623 [==============================] - 2986s 391ms/step - loss: 1.6407 - accuracy: 0.5965 - val_loss: 2.2926 - val_accuracy: 0.5112
Epoch 6/10
7623/7623 [==============================] - 3207s 420ms/step - loss: 1.3775 - accuracy: 0.6464 - val_loss: 2.3429 - val_accuracy: 0.5142
Epoch 7/10
7623/7623 [==============================] - 3213s 421ms/step - loss: 1.1607 - accuracy: 0.6931 - val_loss: 2.5458 - val_accuracy: 0.5152
Epoch 8/10
7623/7623 [==============================] - 3219s 422ms/step - loss: 0.9805 - accuracy: 0.7308 - val_loss: 2.5788 - val_accuracy: 0.5157
Epoch 9/10
7623/7623 [==============================] - 3399s 445ms/step - loss: 0.8374 - accuracy: 0.7638 - val_loss: 2.8998 - val_accuracy: 0.5039
Epoch 10/10
7623/7623 [==============================] - 3188s 418ms/step - loss: 0.7226 - accuracy: 0.7914 - val_loss: 2.8231 - val_accuracy: 0.5128

Any specific reasons why you're defining custom model architecture/training from scratch? If the ultimate goal is to have a model that generalizes well on unseen datasets, usually using a pre-trained model and fine-tuning on your custom datasets would give you a better head start.

Also, larger models tend to generalize well better. Although you're right that a larger model has a higher tendency to overfit, you don't necessarily need to reduce its complexity to avoid overfitting - there are other methods you can try out like image augmentation, weight decay, more aggressive dropout, etc

I write it from scratch because it's part of my thesis. I try to test out different methods to reduce overfitting but training takes up around 12 hours so it takes a lot of time to test out everything.
